# Присваивание c++

Tags: c++, строки

Доброго времени суток, возник такой вопрос:
Имеется переменная - 'A' допустим со значением 524.
Мне нужно произвести определенные операции с каждой частью A.
То есть над 5, 2 и 4. 
Как это сделать ?
Думал в массив загнать и по индексам все сделать но нет... будет целое число 524...
Язык с++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте операцию "получение остатка при делении на 10"

```
int A = 524;
int B[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  B[i] = A % 10;
  A /= 10;
}
```

Comment: а, понял) и вспомнил за одно, спасибо :)